# is there a way to get the progress of the page rendering in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When the page is still loading I would like to display a transition of 4 images in the background, just until the page fully loads.
But I would like to know the progress so that if the page is loaded about 25% percent I would display the second image, 50% third image and so on.
Is there a way to achieve this ? if no then would you suggest some other way to do so ? thanks.

Comment: The page load depends on multiple factors, including client's connection speed, the size of the page and it's assets, etc., so this is not possible. What you could do is test the page load times on various devices and network speeds and take the average of this as the length of the animation.

Another thing you could do is to create a fixed-length animation and load the content after your animation is finished, so it would always show as expected despite page already being loaded in the background.

Comment: @askepott has some good suggestions. I would also query why your page is taking so long to load that you need to show 4 images? It would probably be a better experience to get the page to load quicker

Comment: @RedBaron the page is not taking long to load, it's just that the client asked for that animation, and I thought since I'm using it why not take advantage and load the rest of the page in the background. I do agree that askepott has a some good suggestions, and that's what I'm gonna do. thank you guys !